# Converting large files from AAX to M4B causes unusable files in iTunes/iPods

Tags: ffmpeg, audiobook, m4b

I am converting audiobooks from AAX to M4B with the command:

`ffmpeg -activation_bytes xxxxxxxx -i BOOK.AAX -c copy book.m4b`

This command works for most books, but large files over approximately 750 MB have an incorrect duration in iTunes and iPods. Musicbee and other programs I've tried work normally. Seeking through the file is not possible, but chapter markers work fine.

Command output:

```
c:\Utilities\ffmpeg-20200921\bin>ffmpeg -activation_bytes xxxxxxxx -i "E:\test.AAX" -c copy "E:\test.m4b"
ffmpeg version N-99335-gdfbea7b210 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --disable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp
  libavutil      56. 59.100 / 56. 59.100
  libavcodec     58.106.100 / 58.106.100
  libavformat    58. 58.100 / 58. 58.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.102 / 58. 11.102
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025962c54e00] [aax] file checksum == 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000025962c54e00] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'E:\test.AAX':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : aax
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: aax M4B mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2020-09-08T15:53:16.000000Z
    comment         : Chapter 93
    title           : The Name of the Wind: Kingkiller Chronicle, Book 1
    artist          : Patrick Rothfuss
    album_artist    : Patrick Rothfuss
    album           : The Name of the Wind: Kingkiller Chronicle, Book 1
    genre           : Audiobook
    copyright       : ©2009 DAW Trade (P)2009 Brilliance Audio, Inc.
    date            : 2009
  Duration: 27:55:57.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 190.728707
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 190.728707, end 2725.233197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 2725.233197, end 3225.391020
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 3225.391020, end 5021.593832
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 5021.593832, end 5751.768526
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 5751.768526, end 6188.953832
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 6188.953832, end 7423.140862
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 7423.140862, end 8230.312925
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 8230.312925, end 9876.468390
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 9876.468390, end 10645.652608
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 10645.652608, end 11047.822222
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 11047.822222, end 12023.989116
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 12023.989116, end 13666.150748
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 13666.150748, end 14568.338866
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 14568.338866, end 16003.517823
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 16003.517823, end 16770.705125
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 16770.705125, end 18187.865397
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 18187.865397, end 18494.043719
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 18494.043719, end 19109.233197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0:19: start 19109.233197, end 19729.438186
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0:20: start 19729.438186, end 20937.618866
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0:21: start 20937.618866, end 21563.814603
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0:22: start 21563.814603, end 23176.997732
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0:23: start 23176.997732, end 25249.192925
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Chapter #0:24: start 25249.192925, end 25489.380136
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 25
    Chapter #0:25: start 25489.380136, end 25784.552200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 26
    Chapter #0:26: start 25784.552200, end 28231.749660
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 27
    Chapter #0:27: start 28231.749660, end 28624.909932
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 28
    Chapter #0:28: start 28624.909932, end 29539.079546
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 29
    Chapter #0:29: start 29539.079546, end 29846.279546
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 30
    Chapter #0:30: start 29846.279546, end 30200.476735
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 31
    Chapter #0:31: start 30200.476735, end 31098.671020
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 32
    Chapter #0:32: start 31098.671020, end 32217.826395
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 33
    Chapter #0:33: start 32217.826395, end 32899.006984
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 34
    Chapter #0:34: start 32899.006984, end 33457.168254
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 35
    Chapter #0:35: start 33457.168254, end 33851.350204
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 36
    Chapter #0:36: start 33851.350204, end 35979.551927
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 37
    Chapter #0:37: start 35979.551927, end 37586.697868
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 38
    Chapter #0:38: start 37586.697868, end 38888.872925
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 39
    Chapter #0:39: start 38888.872925, end 39644.078730
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 40
    Chapter #0:40: start 39644.078730, end 41362.262494
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 41
    Chapter #0:41: start 41362.262494, end 42204.450249
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 42
    Chapter #0:42: start 42204.450249, end 43088.619683
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 43
    Chapter #0:43: start 43088.619683, end 45214.778050
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 44
    Chapter #0:44: start 45214.778050, end 46355.945941
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 45
    Chapter #0:45: start 46355.945941, end 46616.148753
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 46
    Chapter #0:46: start 46616.148753, end 48366.329615
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 47
    Chapter #0:47: start 48366.329615, end 48727.492789
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 48
    Chapter #0:48: start 48727.492789, end 49112.665397
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 49
    Chapter #0:49: start 49112.665397, end 49490.872018
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 50
    Chapter #0:50: start 49490.872018, end 50915.044717
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 51
    Chapter #0:51: start 50915.044717, end 51550.203356
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 52
    Chapter #0:52: start 51550.203356, end 53249.393197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 53
    Chapter #0:53: start 53249.393197, end 54093.577868
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 54
    Chapter #0:54: start 54093.577868, end 56342.755556
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 55
    Chapter #0:55: start 56342.755556, end 56432.941859
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 56
    Chapter #0:56: start 56432.941859, end 57963.136871
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 57
    Chapter #0:57: start 57963.136871, end 58539.316825
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 58
    Chapter #0:58: start 58539.316825, end 59977.514376
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 59
    Chapter #0:59: start 59977.514376, end 60076.663583
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 60
    Chapter #0:60: start 60076.663583, end 61934.863673
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 61
    Chapter #0:61: start 61934.863673, end 63462.040091
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 62
    Chapter #0:62: start 63462.040091, end 64937.203810
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 63
    Chapter #0:63: start 64937.203810, end 65434.389478
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 64
    Chapter #0:64: start 65434.389478, end 66356.593197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 65
    Chapter #0:65: start 66356.593197, end 67552.792381
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 66
    Chapter #0:66: start 67552.792381, end 68699.951020
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 67
    Chapter #0:67: start 68699.951020, end 69503.129252
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 68
    Chapter #0:68: start 69503.129252, end 71055.290340
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 69
    Chapter #0:69: start 71055.290340, end 73339.483719
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 70
    Chapter #0:70: start 73339.483719, end 74739.646984
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 71
    Chapter #0:71: start 74739.646984, end 76989.799909
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 72
    Chapter #0:72: start 76989.799909, end 79985.081179
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 73
    Chapter #0:73: start 79985.081179, end 81746.268299
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 74
    Chapter #0:74: start 81746.268299, end 82711.428934
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 75
    Chapter #0:75: start 82711.428934, end 82815.593651
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 76
    Chapter #0:76: start 82815.593651, end 83242.794376
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 77
    Chapter #0:77: start 83242.794376, end 85966.030658
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 78
    Chapter #0:78: start 85966.030658, end 86589.207800
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 79
    Chapter #0:79: start 86589.207800, end 87930.392381
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 80
    Chapter #0:80: start 87930.392381, end 89250.586122
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 81
    Chapter #0:81: start 89250.586122, end 89325.772336
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 82
    Chapter #0:82: start 89325.772336, end 90794.945306
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 83
    Chapter #0:83: start 90794.945306, end 91014.141678
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 84
    Chapter #0:84: start 91014.141678, end 92237.322449
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 85
    Chapter #0:85: start 92237.322449, end 92911.490612
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 86
    Chapter #0:86: start 92911.490612, end 93676.680998
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 87
    Chapter #0:87: start 93676.680998, end 94375.880272
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 88
    Chapter #0:88: start 94375.880272, end 97204.117188
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 89
    Chapter #0:89: start 97204.117188, end 97281.300317
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 90
    Chapter #0:90: start 97281.300317, end 98427.483719
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 91
    Chapter #0:91: start 98427.483719, end 98986.666667
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 92
    Chapter #0:92: start 98986.666667, end 100557.740000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 93
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (aavd / 0x64766161), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-09-08T15:53:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: bin_data (text / 0x74786574) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-09-08T15:53:18.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Text Media Handler
    Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x500 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
Output #0, ipod, to 'E:\test.m4b':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : aax
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: aax M4B mp42isom
    date            : 2009
    comment         : Chapter 93
    title           : The Name of the Wind: Kingkiller Chronicle, Book 1
    artist          : Patrick Rothfuss
    album_artist    : Patrick Rothfuss
    album           : The Name of the Wind: Kingkiller Chronicle, Book 1
    genre           : Audiobook
    copyright       : ©2009 DAW Trade (P)2009 Brilliance Audio, Inc.
    encoder         : Lavf58.58.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 190.728707
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 190.728707, end 2725.233197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 2725.233197, end 3225.391020
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 3225.391020, end 5021.593832
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 5021.593832, end 5751.768526
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 5751.768526, end 6188.953832
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 6188.953832, end 7423.140862
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 7423.140862, end 8230.312925
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 8230.312925, end 9876.468390
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 9876.468390, end 10645.652608
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 10645.652608, end 11047.822222
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 11047.822222, end 12023.989116
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 12023.989116, end 13666.150748
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 13666.150748, end 14568.338866
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 14568.338866, end 16003.517823
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 16003.517823, end 16770.705125
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 16770.705125, end 18187.865397
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 18187.865397, end 18494.043719
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0:18: start 18494.043719, end 19109.233197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0:19: start 19109.233197, end 19729.438186
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0:20: start 19729.438186, end 20937.618866
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0:21: start 20937.618866, end 21563.814603
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0:22: start 21563.814603, end 23176.997732
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0:23: start 23176.997732, end 25249.192925
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Chapter #0:24: start 25249.192925, end 25489.380136
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 25
    Chapter #0:25: start 25489.380136, end 25784.552200
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 26
    Chapter #0:26: start 25784.552200, end 28231.749660
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 27
    Chapter #0:27: start 28231.749660, end 28624.909932
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 28
    Chapter #0:28: start 28624.909932, end 29539.079546
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 29
    Chapter #0:29: start 29539.079546, end 29846.279546
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 30
    Chapter #0:30: start 29846.279546, end 30200.476735
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 31
    Chapter #0:31: start 30200.476735, end 31098.671020
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 32
    Chapter #0:32: start 31098.671020, end 32217.826395
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 33
    Chapter #0:33: start 32217.826395, end 32899.006984
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 34
    Chapter #0:34: start 32899.006984, end 33457.168254
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 35
    Chapter #0:35: start 33457.168254, end 33851.350204
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 36
    Chapter #0:36: start 33851.350204, end 35979.551927
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 37
    Chapter #0:37: start 35979.551927, end 37586.697868
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 38
    Chapter #0:38: start 37586.697868, end 38888.872925
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 39
    Chapter #0:39: start 38888.872925, end 39644.078730
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 40
    Chapter #0:40: start 39644.078730, end 41362.262494
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 41
    Chapter #0:41: start 41362.262494, end 42204.450249
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 42
    Chapter #0:42: start 42204.450249, end 43088.619683
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 43
    Chapter #0:43: start 43088.619683, end 45214.778050
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 44
    Chapter #0:44: start 45214.778050, end 46355.945941
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 45
    Chapter #0:45: start 46355.945941, end 46616.148753
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 46
    Chapter #0:46: start 46616.148753, end 48366.329615
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 47
    Chapter #0:47: start 48366.329615, end 48727.492789
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 48
    Chapter #0:48: start 48727.492789, end 49112.665397
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 49
    Chapter #0:49: start 49112.665397, end 49490.872018
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 50
    Chapter #0:50: start 49490.872018, end 50915.044717
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 51
    Chapter #0:51: start 50915.044717, end 51550.203356
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 52
    Chapter #0:52: start 51550.203356, end 53249.393197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 53
    Chapter #0:53: start 53249.393197, end 54093.577868
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 54
    Chapter #0:54: start 54093.577868, end 56342.755556
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 55
    Chapter #0:55: start 56342.755556, end 56432.941859
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 56
    Chapter #0:56: start 56432.941859, end 57963.136871
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 57
    Chapter #0:57: start 57963.136871, end 58539.316825
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 58
    Chapter #0:58: start 58539.316825, end 59977.514376
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 59
    Chapter #0:59: start 59977.514376, end 60076.663583
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 60
    Chapter #0:60: start 60076.663583, end 61934.863673
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 61
    Chapter #0:61: start 61934.863673, end 63462.040091
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 62
    Chapter #0:62: start 63462.040091, end 64937.203810
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 63
    Chapter #0:63: start 64937.203810, end 65434.389478
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 64
    Chapter #0:64: start 65434.389478, end 66356.593197
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 65
    Chapter #0:65: start 66356.593197, end 67552.792381
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 66
    Chapter #0:66: start 67552.792381, end 68699.951020
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 67
    Chapter #0:67: start 68699.951020, end 69503.129252
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 68
    Chapter #0:68: start 69503.129252, end 71055.290340
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 69
    Chapter #0:69: start 71055.290340, end 73339.483719
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 70
    Chapter #0:70: start 73339.483719, end 74739.646984
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 71
    Chapter #0:71: start 74739.646984, end 76989.799909
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 72
    Chapter #0:72: start 76989.799909, end 79985.081179
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 73
    Chapter #0:73: start 79985.081179, end 81746.268299
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 74
    Chapter #0:74: start 81746.268299, end 82711.428934
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 75
    Chapter #0:75: start 82711.428934, end 82815.593651
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 76
    Chapter #0:76: start 82815.593651, end 83242.794376
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 77
    Chapter #0:77: start 83242.794376, end 85966.030658
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 78
    Chapter #0:78: start 85966.030658, end 86589.207800
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 79
    Chapter #0:79: start 86589.207800, end 87930.392381
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 80
    Chapter #0:80: start 87930.392381, end 89250.586122
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 81
    Chapter #0:81: start 89250.586122, end 89325.772336
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 82
    Chapter #0:82: start 89325.772336, end 90794.945306
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 83
    Chapter #0:83: start 90794.945306, end 91014.141678
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 84
    Chapter #0:84: start 91014.141678, end 92237.322449
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 85
    Chapter #0:85: start 92237.322449, end 92911.490612
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 86
    Chapter #0:86: start 92911.490612, end 93676.680998
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 87
    Chapter #0:87: start 93676.680998, end 94375.880272
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 88
    Chapter #0:88: start 94375.880272, end 97204.117188
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 89
    Chapter #0:89: start 97204.117188, end 97281.300317
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 90
    Chapter #0:90: start 97281.300317, end 98427.483719
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 91
    Chapter #0:91: start 98427.483719, end 98986.666667
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 92
    Chapter #0:92: start 98986.666667, end 100557.740000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 93
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x500 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-09-08T15:53:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  779347kB time=27:55:57.72 bitrate=  63.5kbits/s speed=1.21e+03x
video:68kB audio:770806kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.099302%
```

I know this works correctly on older versions (3.1.4 for sure), but old versions do not copy artwork without a separate program. Note, the format flag is required on the old version and I've tried it on new versions with no effect:

`ffmpeg -activation_bytes xxxxxxxx -i BOOK.AAX -c copy -f mp4 book.m4b`

I thought maybe the cover artwork was the issue and tried the -vn flag with no effect. However, converting to AAC first and then to M4B outputs a working file. These commands output a good file, without chapters, cover art, etc:

```
ffmpeg -activation_bytes XXXX -i "book.AAX" -c:a copy "temp.aac"
ffmpeg -i "temp.aac" -c:a copy "book.m4b"
```

Is there a command parameter to fix these larger files (besides throwing out the iPod)? It seems like a bug to me, but I hesitate to submit since I have little experience with ffmpeg.

Comment: How about `ffmpeg -activation_bytes XXXX -i "book.AAX" -map 0 -c copy "temp.m4a"` and then `ffmpeg -i "temp.m4a" -map 0 -c copy "book.m4b"`?

Comment: -map 0 produced an error `[ipod @ 0000026aafb3dc80] Tag text incompatible with output codec id '100359' ([0][0][0][0])
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input` I added -f mp4 to your command and the output has the same incorrect duration.

Comment: In place of `-map 0`, put `-map 0:a -map 0:v`

Comment: Same result, incorrect duration.